# Android Azure: 404 Error when attempting to retrieve data from the Server

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to access a Table in my Azure DB and the Code is fine (I believe so or as it seems) but when trying to retrieve table data from the Server, it returns a '404 code' with an exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: {'code': 404}
```

Here's my code:

```
if (isInternetConnected == true) {
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        try {
                            //ActivityContent is the column I'm trying to retrieve from
                            final MobileServiceList<ActivityTable> result = mToDoTable.select("ActivityContent").execute().get();
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {


                                    for (ActivityTable item : result) {

                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item.getActivity(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (Exception exception) {
                            Log.d("AZURE_Error", exception.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                }.execute();
            }
```

Comment: I'd start with making sure the service itself is working. Create a custom API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn280974.aspx if you are using the Node backend) that simply returns a string response (no database) and is an operation open to Everyone.  Try hitting that with a browser, Postman (Chrome REST client), etc. to see if you get the response.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error too today.  I had created a table directly in the database but that won't work.

After many hours of frustration, I discovered that setting up my Mobile Service using a .NET backend was my problem.  After recreating the Mobile Service with a javascript backend, I finally had access to the fabled DATA tab I kept reading about, and I was able to create the table there.  Once the table was created there, this error went away for me and everything started working.